# Throwing exception from custom error handler in PHP

Tags: php, apache, exception, crash, php-7

I was working on resource streams and more specifically on [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).
This function throws a warning when failing, in addition to returning false instead of a resource. The unwanted warnings beings a problem I decided to suppress them.

Two possibilities came to my mind: using the error-suppression operator [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) or using [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)(). And having been told that @ had not so good performances and posed often more problem than it resolved, I ran a quick benchmark to see how set_error_handler() fared against it.

And here comes the problematic code:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function errorHandler(int $errorNumber, string $errorMessage)
{
    throw new \Exception();
}

$previousHandler = set_error_handler("errorHandler");

$operations = 10000;

for($i = 0; $i < $operations; $i++) {
    try{
        $inexistant[0];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {}
}

set_error_handler($previousHandler);

echo 'ok';
```

Running this simple code will crash the apache server with this message:

`[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6000:tid 244] AH00428: Parent: child process 3904 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.`

After searching, this message means that the server had an access violation error, mainly in the case of reaching the stack size limit. This however should not be the case as this code should not increase the stack size (and in fact, it doesn't increase the PHP stack frames).

I also tested if the timing was important but even with a sleep of 3ms between each iteration the crash happen after more or less the same number of iteration. This number is around 700 but fluctuate very slightly, sometimes running fine at 704 and sometimes not.

Also, searching on the php bug tracker doesn’t show anything relevant, except maybe for this [bug entry](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64312) which talk about the fact that there is handling around the call to the handling function. This could mean there is a possibility the exception could bypass some handling on the exit of the function, but as I don't know a thing about the PHP source code, this is pure speculation.

As I would like to propagate the error message properly, the way using set_error_handler() would be the most legible way, but I know I can use [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php)() and the @ operator to achieve the same goal with a lot more code (as there is multiple functions like fopen() called one after another in the real projet).

So here are the questions: Is this a bug of PHP? Is there a way to circumvent this problem while keeping clear code?

Thanks.

PS: I know the reason for the benchmark is... dubious at best and I should take whatever code is the most legible as long as the performances are viable, but it still made me discover this interesting point of code.

Edit: I forgot to put the versions I tested this against:

- Windows 7, Apache 2.4.38, PHP 7.3.2 via XAMPP
- Windows 7, Apache 2.4.29, PHP 7.2.2 via XAMPP
- Ubuntu Server 18.04, Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu), PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this was has been confirmed as a PHP bug and the exact reason was found, I'll post both the answers and how to solve this until the bug is solved.

First, here is the bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77693.

It is a stack overflow caused the capture of the exception context, which in this case include the function calling the error handler as this is in his behavior to capture the parent context. This parent context include the previoulsy caught exception, which is added to the context of the new exception to be caught, and repeating ad vitam aeternam until a crash.

As the reason is clearly determined, the solution is simple: Just add an unset() to the end of the catch block, like so:

```php
$operations = 10000;

for($i = 0; $i < $operations; $i++) {
    try{
        $inexistant[0];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        unset($e);
    }
}
```

Then there is no more problem.

To add to the second question asking for clean alternatives in the case of fopen, and other methods like it, here is a solution:

```
function throwLastError() {
    $context = error_get_last();
    error_clear_last();
    throw new ErrorException($context["message"],
                             0,
                             $context["type"],
                             $context["file"],
                             $context["line"]);
}

// Wrong call to fopen
if (!@fopen("", "a"))
    throwLastError();
```

Both answers have around the same performances, the @ method being 10% slower, when all the error parameters are used in both.

Answer (score 0):

Why go through all this hassle? It would be a lot better to just handle the return value of `false`, since the docs state: `Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.` Therefore it should be sufficient to just check if the return value of `fopen` is false and then continue operation based on that (or throw your own error if necessary).

Comment: This function (fopen) will still throw a warning if it fails. In the case where you suppress the error with @, if you want to get the informations about the error you need to call error_get_last, and get the informations from there. This add quite a bit of code since fopen (and other function of the same kind) are called multiples times, though I could create a function just to handle these errors and throw, you're right on this point. This still leave the question about whether or not this is a bug.

Comment: @Baldorien, you can just ignore that warning, in a production environment your warnings should never be displayed to the user and therefore do not pose a problem. Additonally you can check standard things like if the file exists is readable/writeable to catch common cases of fopen failure

Comment: While I agree on the fact that PHP errors should not be displayed to users, I disagree on the point that they can be ignored, as warning are there for a reason and having potentialy a great numbers of warning is a good way to get heavy and less readable log file. And file existance is just one of the many things that can go wrong with IO.  It still leaves one of main questions : Is this a bug of PHP?

Comment: Yes I agree with you and yes I would consider this a bug in PHP. Since it generates both a warning AND returns false. A good implementation of `fopen` would have been return contents and throw Exception if anything fails. That would mean that a developer can catch this Exception and handle it accordingly. Sadly this is not possible with the E_WARNINg aside from using `@` which (as you mentioned) decreases performance. So sadly there is not a perfect solution for this and you could consider this an issue of PHP

Comment: I am not talking about the implementation of fopen here, so I may have badly writtent my question. I am talking about the crash of the apache server with the script in my question because this may also be an undocumented or misdocumented but "normal" behavior considering the documentation of PHP not always being exhaustive. I'll close this question, consider it a bug and add it to the tracker then.